# How do I incorporate a raw_input as an argument in a function

Tags: python

I'm making a small github script for myself. I'm trying to have the call command with an argument then raw input as another argument. I have no idea how to even start.

```
  file = raw_input("enter file name:  ")
  call(["command", "argument", "input here"])
```

How do i add the incorporate the raw input?

Comment: You don't need to quote arguments in this case (passing it as list of arguments), only if the command is executed through a shell (using `shell=True`).

Comment: Syntactic quotes are consumed by the shell, not passed to your command. If you're calling an external command directly, without any shell, you thus don't need, and thus *must not use*, syntactic quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to just put your raw_input into your call:

```
call(["command", "argument", raw_input("enter file name:  ")])
```

Comment: @MichaelDarnell I have reposted the answer that worked for you without all the edits from before!

Comment: (deleting posts while commenting sucks if you at the same time ask for input!)   The current solution does work (as the OP mentions), IMHO it's not really good because it doesn't explain the assignment of strings to names, and then passing them on. This IMHO is relevant in this case, as the OP is obviously quite new to the language or even programming in general - so I went out a bit more to explain. If you *should* delete it I do honestly not know - I'm not good at StackOverflow Meta-Questions. HTH

Comment: @deets Because my answer does work I am going to leave it up in case someone comes and wants a quick answer this question even outside of it's current context (editing question to reflect what is answered) but I do completely agree that your answer is very in depth and I have voted it up in hopes it shows higher.

Comment: @deets Please feel free to tell me if you disagree with me keeping my answer up.

Comment: as I said - I don't know these meta things that well. Your corrected answer is correct, so IMHO no harm in keeping it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
file_name = raw_input("enter file name:  ")
call(["command", "argument", file_name])
```

Please don't use file as variable, it's a python type

And you don't need quotes, because file_name will be a string that you can put directly in your list.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to confuse strings with string-literals. The first one is a sequence of characters (actually strings again in Python), whereas the latter is a way to write such a string within a program.

So

```
foo = "my string"
```

does not contain any actual quotes. E.g. the length is 9, the first character `foo[0]` is `m` and so forth.

`raw_input` returns a string-object, so if it's content should be passed on, you can just take the variable you assigned it to & and pass it as argument to create a list that in turn you pass to subprocess:

```
 user_input = raw_input()
 subprocess.check_call(["program", user_input])
```

For your actual use-case, don't be confused by having to use quotes in the shell for certain use-cases, as these serve a similar purpose there. The shell tokenizes input by spaces, so

```
 $ command arg1 arg2 arg3
```

will be 3 arguments for `command`. But if you need one argument to contain spaces (e.g. certain filenames with spaces in them), you need to do

```
 $ command "my spaceful argument"
```

However, the Python subprocess module (unless you use `shell=True`) does not suffer from this problem: there the arguments you pass as list will immediately be passed to the child-process without the need for quotes.

Comment: It's worth expressing that this distinction between syntactic and literal quotes isn't just a Python thing, but also exists in shell (thus that the quotes the OP _thinks_ they need to add are actually only for the shell's consumption, thus moot if they have no shell).